# Create after insert trigger that updates record in parent table after inserting record into child table

Tags: sql, ms-access, triggers

I have two tables

`License(licenseId, licenseNumber, lastUsed)`

`User(userId, userName, dateAdded, licenseId)`

After adding a user to a respective license I would like to update the lastUsed field with the most recent date found within the user table using the license.

I am using MS Access

Comment: What version of Access are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are using Access 2010 you can create an `After Insert` Data Macro on the [User] table, something like this:

[image: AfterInsert.png]

Comment: curious as to why the Alias in the second Look up record did not need to be set, is it set to default to License?